# What is the proper way to wait for reactive variables in tests?

Tags: jestjs, apollo-client, react-testing-library, reactive-variable

Given a reactive variable

```js
export const isLoggedInVar: ReactiveVar<boolean> = cache.makeVar<boolean>(
  !!localStorage.getItem("apiToken")
);
```

A logout hook simplified as:

```js
function useLogout(): Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>> {
  const client = useApolloClient();
  const [loggedOut, setLogout] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const resetCache = async (): Promise<void> => {
      localStorage.clear(); // remove api token
      isLoggedInVar(false); // update reactive variable
      client.resetStore();
    };

    if (loggedOut) {
      resetCache();
    }
  }, [loggedOut, client]);

  return setLogout;
}
```

And a component that calls the hook:

```tsx
const ProfileHeader: React.FC = () => {
  const setLogout = useLogout();

  return isLoggedInVar() ? (
      <p>
        <Link to="/settings/">
          <span className="m-auto">Settings</span>
        </Link>

        <button
          type="button"
          data-testid="logout-button"
          onClick={(): void => setLogout(true)}
        >
          Log out
        </button>
      </p>
  ) : null;
};
```

When I write a test for the component, I'm forced to use `await waitFor(() => {});` in the test.

```js
describe("ProfileHeader", () => {
  it("should allow users to logout", async () => {
    isLoggedInVar(true);

    const { container, getByTestId, queryByTestId } = renderApollo(
      <MemoryRouter>
        <ProfileHeader />
      </MemoryRouter>
    );

    expect(isLoggedInVar()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(getByTestId("logout-button")).toBeTruthy();
    userEvent.click(getByTestId("logout-button"));

    waitForElementToBeRemoved(queryByTestId("logout-button"));
    expect(localStorage.getItem("apiToken")).toBeNull();

    // await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0)); // works too
    await waitFor(() => {});
    expect(isLoggedInVar()).toBeFalsy();
  });
});
```

But the [testing-library documentation mentions](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async#wait-deprecated-use-waitfor-instead):

> it is considered bad practice to use an empty callback because it will make the tests more fragile.

I really want to do:

```diff
- await waitFor(() => {});
- expect(isLoggedInVar()).toBeFalsy();
+ await waitFor(() => expect(isLoggedInVar()).toBeFalsy());
```

But this gives me countless errors

> An update to ProfileHeader inside a test was not wrapped in act(...).

Which I'm not understanding.

What would be the proper way for my test to wait for the reactive variable to change ?

Comment: How do you know we are suppose to wait for them? Each time I pull in an action that sets my reactive var into my test file, the function is undefined